# can't access/delete or retake ownership of previous MyPictures folder (win7)

Tags: windows-7, ownership, file-permissions

I have a directory called *pics* which was configured as *My Pictures* folder, now I changed the location to another directory but I can't remove the old *pics* folder. When I go to the security properties it says *Unable to display current owner* and I can't take ownership, neither through that security dialog nor through *takeown*. I've also tried to change the ACLs using *cacls* but all those result in the same *access denied* message. 
I'd appreciate any hint.

thanks,

Raoul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems there's no other way than to boot into safe mode to do it. That worked at least. Typical Microsoft bullcrap.