# How to recover from denying all rights/permissions to open my disk drives in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I mistakenly denied all rights to open my disk drives, including administrator. Now I cannot access any of my disk drives.

Is there a workaround for this? Windows 7 won't let me create a new user or account. Everything is locked up.

Answer (score 0):

If you've changed all the permissions on all folders under `C:` you've probably hosed your Windows 7 installation. There are too many distinct ACLs for it to be worth putting them back in place.

As far as fixing this goes, you should be able to change ownership of a folder to your account and then once you take ownership you can change the security settings again.

Comment: Is SU a forums now? Why quote the OP's entire question?

Answer (score 0):

#### Follow these steps:

- Enable the built in Administrator ([*Click for Steps*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555910/en-us))
- After you enable the built-in Administrator, log off your current user
- Log in to the built-in Administrator account
- Attempt to disable UAC while logged in to the built-in Administrator account. ([*Methods to disable*](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/12/30/how-to-disable-and-turn-off-uac-in-windows-7/))
- After disabling the UAC, then reboot your system.
- Boot in safe mode via F8 during boot-up but before the Windows Logo appears
- While in safe mode, make the wanted changes to the drives. ([*Credit*](https://superuser.com/questions/165360/cant-access-delete-or-retake-ownership-of-previous-mypictures-folder-win7))
- Reboot and confirm work.
- Disable the built-in Administrator account.
- Enable Window's UAC.

***Warning**: Disable the Administrator Account and Enable UAC when finish for security reasons.*